# Custom fonts stopped loading after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I cannot load my custom fonts anymore after upgrading to Android Studio 2.2 preview 3 from 2.1...

```
It throws this: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.class/com.my.class.aoeifjaweof}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found
```

Comment: From error looks like you don't have font file or probably its file name changed somehow. Also make sure your asset folder is under `main` not `res`.

Comment: That's what you would think.  0 code changes were made, and it was loading properly before upgrading Android Studio.  The location of the font is under "/assets/font/my-custom-font.otf" and I am staring at it in the finder

Comment: Is `assets` under `main`? My fonts folder name is `fonts` not `font` (but I am not sure that would cause this issue).

Comment: ah sorry that was a typo I just made in SO, yeah it's under: main/assets/fonts (with an s)

Comment: can you show more code and screenshot of where u put the my-custom-font.otf ?

Comment: Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/my-custom-font.otf");  //this worked before, nothing about this has changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. It looks like an Android Studio 2.2 bug. After cleaning the project, it worked. But cleaning the entire project takes time.. I hope this will be fixed soon by Android Studio team